# SWFObject not able to read/write in CQ5.6.1

Tags: javascript, aem, swfobject

I am trying to create a chart and display as a flash object in CQ 5.6.1. I have created a servlet in glassfish which will be called from my CQ component to provide the data for the charts. I want to access the SWFObject as /etc/clientlibs/myproject/am/amstock.swf. Below is the javascript code sbippet in my component jsp.

```
var so = new SWFObject("/etc/clientlibs/myproject/am/amstock.swf", "amstock", "600", "400", "8", "#FFFFFF");        
var uri = "http://localhost:8080/mycharts/apps/CreateXMLFileServlet?r="+Math.random()+"&fc=03&fc=04"; //Servlet hosted in Glassfish
so.addVariable("settings_file", encodeURIComponent(uri));
so.addVariable("chart_id", "amstock");
so.addVariable("key", "106-d0564444fe0a5ce6839d84f70655375c");
so.write("flashcontent");
```

However CQ fails to access the swf object. When I keep the swfobject in the glassfish server and access it from the CQ component JSP as below, it works and displays the chart with no change to rest of the code.

```
var so = new SWFObject("http://localhost:8080/mycharts/am/amstock.swf", "amstock", "600", "400", "8", "#FFFFFF");
```

I am not sure why it is not working when I keep the object in CQ. Appreciate any suggestions to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed. The issue was with the swfobject. I deleted the object from etc/clientlibs/myproject/am and used CRXDE (the eclipse IDE) to copy the amstock.swf to the same path. It worked after copying the new file.